# error "the action was blocked by organization policy ms office 2016"

Tags: c#, ms-access, macros, ms-office, vsto

I am working on MS Office plugin. On MS Office previous version then 2016, it works fine but on MS Office 2016, I am getting an error "the action was blocked by organization policy ms office 2016". As i understand, Microsoft added some security in MS Office 2016 to block macros to prevent access. But how can i bypass this security and get rid of this error.

Comment: Getting same error, "The action was blocked by organization policy", but only for some users and only at a particular code line (C# COM Add-in, not using vsto) Range.Paste() of a table row. Any other methods in the add-in works just fine.

Comment: Also seeing the same thing. I'm not running any macros, but the same - sometimes intermittent, sometimes occurring for many hours - error appears "COMException (0x800A18BF): The action was blocked by organization policy.".  I have also seen other COM errors such as "Method is not supported" which come and go along with the other error.

Comment: Can't add much except I'm seeing the same thing. Only on Office 2016, and it happens on the (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.PasteAndFormat) method System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A18BF). Not finding anything on the interwebs, so hoping someone finds it.

Comment: I am working on an addin and have faced the same problems.. I found out that the problem occurs only when the content of the clipboard isn't text.

Comment: Me too - intermittently

Comment: @Wade Hatler or OP, Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Afraid not. It's still out there. I don't have any real users on Office 2016 yet, but I eventually will and I'll have to figure it out. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Do not ceate software that relies on the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and searched for a solution. There are many who suggest modifying security settings, for example, in the MS Word Trust Center or in the Group Policy Settings. However, none of these proposed solutions worked.

There is one solution that did work in my case. I shut down all other applications that access the clipboard. On my PC, applications that were running that access (or monitor) the clipboard include: JWPce, OneNote Quick Note, and SugarSync. I'm sure that there are other applications out there that interface with the clipboard. Y

ou have to shut down all applications that access the clipboard before you run the MS Word macro.

Comment: Be practical. No client is going to shut down their all application for using MS Word Macro